# Variables in Template Haskell custom quasiquoter

Tags: haskell, ghc, template-haskell

An example is worth a thousand words. Here is a pretty simple [quasi quoter](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.11.1.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Quote.html) I just made up.

```
import Language.Haskell.TH.Quote
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax

quoter :: QuasiQuoter
quoter = QuasiQuoter { quotePat = parse }
  where
    parse :: String -> Q Pat
    parse ('$':x) = pure (VarP (mkName x))
    parse "_" = pure WildP
    parse _ = fail "Invalid pattern"
```

Then, using it in GHCi

```
ghci> :set -XQuasiQuotes
ghci> [quoter|_|] = 2
ghci> [quoter|$x|] = 2
ghci> x
error: Variable not in scope: x
```

I would have liked `2` to be bound to `x`. <s>So: is there any way to introduce variable patterns in custom quasi-quotes that we can use again?</s> Note that my actual use case is a fair bit more involved than the above - `parse` actual does some substantial work.

## EDIT

The following works:

```
 ghci> inc [quoter|$x|] = x + 1
 ghci> inc 2
 3
```

and the following doesn't

```
 ghci> let [quoter|$x|] = 1 in x
 error: Variable not in scope: x
```

so is this a bug in GHCi?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the behaviour in GHC 7.10.3.

Comment: @Zeta Cool. I'll try it out on 7.10.3 just to double check, then I'll file a bug. I'll post back here once that's done.

Comment: [Filed as a bug](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/13473#ticket). Note I'm not convinced this is even really a bug....

Comment: You can also reproduce the behaviour with `let $(varP . mkName "x") = 1 in x`. And `-ddump-splices` says that the name gets expanded to `x`. So the behaviour affects TH as whole, not only QQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now fixed in GHC 8.2 (see [this commit](https://git.haskell.org/ghc.git/commitdiff/eaf9cc4240019c2e91922ef38ae7236b59d59bdd)).